# How to make multiline text for messages in ListView with Winform C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, multiline

I'm making a client-server multichat by C# in Visual Studio 2019. But when I add a new message, it is in the same row with the old message and doesn't be in a new line. How can I fix that?

I have tried to use environment.newline but it wasn't just as expected

Thank you so much

```
#here is my code for adding new message in client/server file
void addMessage(string s)
        {
            chatBox.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Text = s });
        }
```

[stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post image here so it use this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km8YC.png)

Comment: What is the `ListView.View` property set to? Have you tried other options?

Comment: I have tried to set ListView.View to List. But only app server changed, another didn't change and I didn't known the reason

Answer (score 0):

Solution : `chatBox.Alignment = ListViewAlignment.Left;`

Or change property Alignment straight in designer in chatBox properties